# Increase force exerted by a body's weight using electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I would like to ask if there is any mechanism that can increase the weight force of a body using electricity. For example, this mechanism is enclosed in a box which normally weighs 1kg but when electricity is supplied to the circuit, the box exerts a force equal to the force of a body of 500kg mass. There are no external factors other than the box and the mechanism inside it.

Comment: Gravity and electromagnetism are wholly independent fundamental forces. Magnetic, electrostatic and electromagnetic levitation are all possible, but they do not affect the weight of the object levitated. If you have read otherwise (and such theories have been suggested), you have been misled.

Comment: I need the opposite of levitation. I need the force to point towards the earth as it was a gravitational force.

Comment: That can be done too, but it still does not change the weight of the object being forced down. Oh, and all these effects require certain external conditions or apparatus to be present.

Comment: I don't want to change the weight, I just need the box to exert 5kN instead of 10N for example in total. If there are no external factors the box would exert the same and opposite force and cancel any other forces right?

Comment: If there are no external factors (so the box would still create downthrust in free fall), then the only solution is to eject reaction mass - a rocket engine. You could use electricity to accelerate the reaction mass, as in an ion rocket, but thrust-to-weight is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

To get that much weight from a small mass you have to push the body from upwards towards the surface of earth.
So you can use a thruster on the upper surface of object..

I got an idea for a mechanism without involvement of any mechanism but that would be very inefficient.
You can use a compound and oxidize it in your box(that would increase the weight but not that much you want and also this is very inefficient as the compound would also self oxidize